# Most symmetric unit cell in a two-dimensional arrangement

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, crystals

Consider the two dimensional structure below, where two atoms A (white) and B (black) are displayed like a brick wall.

[image]

I need to find the most symmetric primitive unit cell of this structure and the unit vectors of this cell. The most symmetric primitive unit cell (I think) I could find was a square with alternating atoms at its vertices, but I noticed that this is not invariant under a translation of $\Delta$.

[image: The "primitive unit cell" I could find]

The other unit cell was a rectangle, following the "bricks", but this one is not primitive.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Define "most symmetric"? There are an infinite number of unit cells, not to mention conventional cells. I tend to think that the Wigner-Seitz cell is the "most symmetric", but it often looks weird to people.

Comment: What's the meaning of the lines joining some black and white circles but not all of them?

Comment: @JonCuster To be honest, the exercise doesn't explain beyond that and my professor's answer to that same question was something like "It's kind of obvious, a square is more symmetric than a rectangle, for example."

Comment: @GiorgioP One of the exercises asked if the "brick" cell and the lines indicate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When faced with a repeating pattern, the conceptual issue is to identify the underlying Bravais lattice and a possible basis to describe the crystalline structure. Of course, there are many (infinite) possibilities for these elements. Still, the constraint of having the minimal basis and the most symmetric primitive unit cell for the Bravais lattice are good guidelines.

The presence of two differently colored circles and only a single pattern of "bonds" around each of them (all the white circles have bonds in the WNE directions, while all the black circles have bonds in the ESW directions) suggest the possibility of a minimal two-atom basis.

The search for the Bravais lattice is quite simple. One can start from a circle of a given color. Then one has to look for the minimum displacements in two linearly independent directions, bringing to a circle *of the same kind and having the same kind of environment*.

In this case, for example, any pair of non-aligned displacements from a black circle to another black circle would be fine. However, there is a straightforward and symmetric choice, as indicated in the following figure. To the best of my ability to measure distances, it looks like a square, a highly symmetric choice.

[image]

With such a choice, the basis is made by any pair of two atoms of a different color.

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding my core difficulty on this question, now I think I understand Bravais lattices better. I just want to clarify one thing. In this case, out primitive unit cell would be the square, with the vectors being the ones you described in the picture, and it would be a primitive unit cell because the atom in the middle is different from those of the vertices?

Comment: @Janne The primitive unit cell should be identified with respect to the Bravais lattice, not to the crystalline structure. Therefore, in the case of a crystalline structure with a basis, you should look only at one atom of the basis. In the example, you may concentrate for example on the black atoms only. With this warning, the squared unit cell connected to the two red segments I drew contains only one black circle (each circle at the corners of the square count for 1/4. The same conclusion could be obtained by displacing the whole lattice along the diagonal of the square.